# IAM access to an API gateway from Lambda resolvers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

My goal is to abstract private networking complexities away from my (AWS VPC managed) Lambda environment to an API gateway.

Assuming I can hook up a private API gateway (it MUST NOT  on the public Internet) in an AWS account to an on-prem downstream system, my concern is how do I control access to the API gateway.

If I do a fetch with one of my lambdas how is IAM conveyed over HTTP to the API gateway? I've looked at various [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html) but it's not clear to me how this is done.

Some fetch augmentation to add AWSv4 signatures? An example would be great.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the authorization on the relevant API resources and methods to `AWS_IAM` (the tab Method Request Settings in the console)
2. Grant an IAM role the permission `execute-api:Invoke` on the relevant API resources and methods
3. [Sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-signing.html) all your requests to the gateway using this role's credentials. Use `execute-api` for the service name when signing.

Alternatively, if you don't want fine-grained permission separation, you can just create a [Usage Plan with an API key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) and have the relevant methods require the API key.